# Problem with inner scrollbars in html file

Tags: html

I have the code delow and every time inner scrollbars appear, which are not browser's scrollbars. The problem is that if browser's window is too small then the user cannot access all menu elements. Is there a way to have only browser's scrollbars when needed? Yes, I know that the code in function deals with the inner scrollbar but what can I do to solve my problem?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }           
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>     
      $(function () {
        const estimatedScrollbarWidth = 30
        $(".content").height($(window).height() - estimatedScrollbarWidth);       
        $(window).resize(function(){
          $(".content").height($(window).height() - estimatedScrollbarWidth);         
        });
      });     

      function showPage(id) {
        switch (id) {
          case "1":           
            $(".content").html('<object data="https://www.purebasic.com">');
            break;
          case "2":
            $(".content").html('<object data="https://www.purebasic.fr/english/">');
            break;
          case "3":
            $(".content").html('<object data="http://www.purearea.net/">');                       
            break;           
          case "4":           
            $(".content").html('<object data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureBasic">');           
            break;
        }
        $(".content object").css({width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: 'auto'});
      }     
    </script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-7">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="1" onclick="showPage(this.id)">PureBasic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2" onclick="showPage(this.id)">PureBasic Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3" onclick="showPage(this.id)">PureArea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="4" onclick="showPage(this.id)">Wikipedia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="5" onclick="showPage(this.id)">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="6" onclick="showPage(this.id)">Blank</a></li>       
        <li><a href="#" id="7" onclick="showPage(this.id)">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="8" onclick="showPage(this.id)">Blank</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear your code and account for the menu height:

```js
$(function () {
  updateHeight();
  $(window).resize(updateHeight);
  $(".menu a").click(function(){ showPage($(this).parent().index()+1+"") });
});

function updateHeight() {
  const estimatedHeight = $(window).height() - $(".menu").height() - 30;
  $(".content").height(estimatedHeight);
}

function showPage(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case "1": $(".content").html('<object data="https://www.purebasic.com">'); break;
    case "2": $(".content").html('<object data="https://www.purebasic.fr/english/">'); break;
    case "3": $(".content").html('<object data="http://www.purearea.net/">'); break;           
    case "4": $(".content").html('<object data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureBasic">'); break;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.content object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">PureBasic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PureBasic Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PureArea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wikipedia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blank</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blank</a></li>       
    <li><a href="#">Blank</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blank</a></li>       
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```